# Adding custom attributes to an order in Magento 1.8 CE

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I want to add a few custom attributes to the sales order. For this, I have created a module Npm_CustomSales.

I followed [Alan Storm's post](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) on how to do this, but my setup script is not getting executed not is it making an entry in the core_resource table for that module.

I want to add a few custom attributes to the sales order. For this, I have created a module Npm_CustomSales.

I followed [Alan Storm's post](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) on how to do this, but my setup script is not getting executed not is it making an entry in the core_resource table for that module.

Here's my file Structure:

```
local
 -Npm
  -CustomSales
   -etc
    -config.xml
   -Model
    -Observer.php
   -sql
    -customsales_setup
     -mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Npm_CustomSales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Npm_CustomSales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customsales_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Npm_CustomSales</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customsales_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
                <observers>
                    <npm_sales>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Npm_CustomSales_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkout</method>
                    </npm_sales>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php

die("Test setup script");
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('order', 'mano_admin_fees', array(
    'type'          => 'currency',
    'label'         => 'Mano admin fees',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true
));

$this->addAttribute('order', 'mano_promotion_fees', array(
    'type'          => 'currency',
    'label'         => 'Mano promotion fees',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true
));

$this->addAttribute('order', 'deja_fees', array(
    'type'          => 'currency',
    'label'         => 'Deja fees',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true
));

$this->addAttribute('order', 'foundation_fees', array(
    'type'          => 'currency',
    'label'         => 'Foundation fees',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true
));

$this->endSetup();
```

I checked Admin>System>Advanced and my module is listed(Enabled) over there.

Also, there is no entry made in the core_resource table.

I issued a die("Test"); on the constructor of Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup and it seems to execute.

Please comment if you need more info to debug.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `Npm_CustomSales` to `Npm_Customsales`

Comment: Changed to Npm_Customsales in <module>, and still does not work.

Comment: Changed it everywhere and still does not work.